# strlen runtime error on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, runtime-error, glibc, strlen

I develop a CGI C++ application that I compiled under Debian. Running this app on an Ubuntu system I am getting the error:

> relocation error: /lib32/libresolv.so.2: symbol strlen, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

What can I do now? Should I recomile on the Ubunto system? Can I replace a library?

### Edit

I link my application with `-static`.
Running the command `ldd --version` on the Ubuntu system showed my that `EGLIB` is used there.

Comment: The C library runtime is intricately tied to your system and kernel. Best to relink your application.

Comment: Or link the application with `-static`.

Comment: There was a comment giving the hint it might be 32/64 bit related. I checked. The Ubunto is a 64 bit system and the Debian system isn't.

Comment: @juergend: good catch. Though 64 bit systems support 32 bit binaries. i.e. you have /lib32 directory - it contains 32 bit runtime

Answer (score 3):

What this error means is that your program was compiled/linked against an older version of GNU libc, which is not supported on the system where you want to run your executable.

You have few options to solve it:

1. Make sure you use the same or compatible version of libc when compiling and running.
2. Link against a static runtime.
3. Install older version of libc on Ubuntu system to match the Debian's environment.

Comment: I do link with `-static`. Do I have to include glibc to my other libraries?